# Black padding/empty space in application on Galaxy Tab

Tags: android

I am new to android and facing a trivial issue.  My application which runs perfectly on emulator without any black padding or empty space, shows black padding/empty space on Samsung Galaxy Tab.

How can I avoid such padding?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your root layout element `layout_width` and `layout_height` set to match_parent, and not some hardcoded value?

It may help us more if you could edit the quesiton and include the code of a layout you're having trouble with and describe if the padding is left, left+right, top, top+bottom, etc

Comment: I got it fixed by using 
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" /> 
<supports-screens 
    android:smallScreens="false" 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true"
/>           in manifest file.